# What is the pythonic term for "async"?

Tags: python

I found the keyword `async` in some Python programs. It was being used just before `def` while defining a function .

I needed to know the grammatical term for `async` (and for `await` too) and other such keywords in its leagues. It seems like some "modifier" like `inline` in C++. So what is the pythonic term for that?

Answer (score 3):

The [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#why-async-def-and-not-def-async) calls `async` a *"statement qualifier"*:

> `async` keyword is a *statement qualifier*. A good analogy to it are "static",
>   "public", "unsafe" keywords from other languages.

Comment: So the general  grammatical form for function definition in python is something like  : "qualifier" def "function name" ( argument list ) :

Comment: @itpdusra as that's the only qualifier, they just break it out separately: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#coroutines. In the full grammar it's just `async_funcdef: 'async' funcdef`.